# Should use many the loop or one loop and check condition inside

Tags: java, c++, c, performance, code-cleanup

I have 2 tasks TaskA and TaskB, TaskA will be processed 10 times, taskB will be processed 20 times. Now there are two solutions to do as below
Solution 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   // do taskA
}
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
   // do taskB
}
```

Solution 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    if (i < 10)
    { 
        //do taskA
    }
   // do taskB
}
```

I want to ask either solution 1 or solution 2 is better for performance and clean code?

Comment: Why not run a benchmark test and see? Right now this seems rather homework-y

Comment: This is quite subjective so might not be suited for SO but from where I see it, solution 1 is cleaner as you clearly split both processes so that if the number of iteration for a specific task changes you don't have to bother changing your test. That said, there's a thirs alternative : 1) Iterate from 0 to 9 and perform both tasks 2) second iteration from 10 to 19 only performing taskB

Comment: The second is only good if you *must* do the tasks alternatingly for 10 steps. Otherwise, it doesn't express what the code is supposed to do, so you should write the first. It's very unlikely that incrementing an integer ten times more will make the slightest difference in performance.

Comment: I want to ask for performance and clean code. This is a small example but in a large project I think it is a big problem.

Comment: @TrungNguyen A) what language? Might be that you are working an a project using C, C++ and java, but I have my doubts. B) Why do you think this is "a big problem" ?

Comment: @tobi303, A) yes, I asked for C, C++ and Java

Comment: @TrungNguyen: You're really asking about three different languages? Sorry, too broad.

Comment: @tobi303,  B)As my little knowledge,  I confuse that in a large project the solution 1 may raise many duplicate of code, but the solution 2 seems slower.

Comment: What do you mean with duplicate of code? The fact that you have 2 for loops?? And what do you mean with "2 seems slower"? Did you measure it? I dont see any reason why any of the two should be significantly slower/faster.

Comment: The decision about whether a question is "primarily opinion based" seems to be *primarily opinion based*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether it makes any performance difference is what taskA and taskB is. But IMO, having single loop with a condition (`i>10`) is going to make the code less readable.

So you could make the equivalent code in a cleaner way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  // do taskA
  // do taskB
}

for (int i = 10; i < 20; ++i)
{
  // do taskB
}
```

This is equivalent to solution 2 and how much better depends on the tasks A and B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is good. But please tell me about solution 1 and solution 2. The solution 1 do 30 loop times, the solution 2 do 20 loop times + 20 checking condition, so which are better.

Comment: Just by comparing the loop counts, it can't be said whether it makes any difference. Technically, the the solution 2 (and my answer) could be better because they loop fewer times. But that in itself is not sufficient to make any performance claims. Execute both and measure the performance to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out several times, it all depends on what the "tasks" are.

One could argue about "style" or "readability", but this is clearly subjective.

So there is not much left for an *objective* answer, except for two points:

- Common best practices
- Performance

---

Regarding the Best Practices, I'd like to refer to [Separation Of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). If the tasks are completely independent (and they obviously are - otherwise you would not even have the chance to change the execution order), then the principle of *Separation of Concerns* suggests to put the execution into two separate loops. So this favors your **first** solution. One could even consider going one step further, and split these into two methods:

```
void executeA(int times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
        // do taskA
    }
}

void executeB(int times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
        // do taskB
    }
}
```

and replace the loops with these methods:

```
executeA(10);
executeB(20);
```

(going even further is possible here, but may miss the point of the question)

---

Regarding the performance, there will usually not be much difference, although details may depend on the tasks and the compiler. Modern compilers are optimizing pretty well, and *might* even unroll the loops, so that the first solution would be equivalent to

```
taskA();
... // 10 times
taskA();
taskB();
... // 20 times
taskB();
```

and the second solution would be equivalent to

```
taskB();
taskA();
... // 10 times
taskB();
taskA();
taskB();
taskB();
... // 10 times
taskB();
taskB();
```

Even if the loops are not unrolled, [Branch Prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) will take care of the `if`. However, the **first** solution would then still be preferable for several reasons:

- (Data) locality, as pointed out [by bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345616/3182664)
- Possible nitty-gritty [compiler- and language specific details](http://shipilev.net/blog/2015/black-magic-method-dispatch/)
- The possibility to *parallelize* the loops.

The latter refers to the fact that you can trivially parallelize a simple loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    taskA();
}
```

For example, in Java (or C++, given that you have an appropriate infrastructure), you can simply throw 10 instances of `taskA` into a thread pool. Also annotating such a loop with something like `#pragma omp parallel` is easily possible (although I'm not familiar with OpenMP). If there is an `if`-condition, this will interfere with most parallelization approaches.

So based on these observations, I'd vote for **solution 1**.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, a lot depends on what type of task is performed in those loops. Although the default choice should be option 1 for readability. 
There is one case though where option 1 **should be** the choice for reasons more than syntactic sugar. If task A and task B will work on their own memory blocks [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) will in most likelihood outperform option 2.

for eg:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
     doSomething = dataBlockForTaskA[i]; // lots of cache hits
}
```

vs.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
    doSomething = dataBlockForTaskB[j]; // fetches some memory around BlockB
    if ( j < 10 ){
         doSOmething = dataBlockForTaskA[j] // oops cache miss
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example solution 2 would be better based on the fact you only loop once. But you would have to account for what logic is in Task A vs Task B.